# subtyping and type coercion

Tags: scala, types

The type `T` below is a subtype of `Fruit`. `Apple` is also a subtype of `Fruit`. So, why doesn't the compiler coerce Apple to T when a type ascription is used below. Why do we need an explicit casting to make it work? What are the rules for coercion when inferring types?

```
trait Fruit
case class Apple(id: String) extends Fruit

type T <: Fruit

val t: T = Apple("apple") // why doesn't the compiler coerce Apple to T?

val t: T = Apple("apple").asInstanceOf[T] // works!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify this a bit. Replce T with Pear and Fruit with Fetus.

```
 trait Fetus
 class Apple extends Fetus
 type Pear <: Fetus

 val t: Pear = new Apple()
```

We declared Fetus, then we said "Apple is Fetus" and then "Pear is Fetus".
Our logic is correct so far. But then we try to "put the apple into the box for pears". And here is our mistake.

Let's consider another example:

```
trait Fetus
class Apple extends Fetus
type Fruit >: Apple <: Fetus

val t: Fruit = new Apple()
```

Here we declared Fetus, then we said "Apple is Fetus" and then we said that "Fruit  is something in the middle between Apple and Fetus". In another words we built following hierarchy: Fetus -> Fruit -> Apple. So, now Apple is subtype of Fruit and you can "put apples into the box for fruit".

UPDATE:

A `Pear` definitely cannot be and `Apple`, like a Cat cannot be a Dog in spite of they both are animals. You can go by hierarchy only vertically but not horizontally:

```
Creature
   |
Animal
  _|_
 /    \
Dog    Cat
        \
       White Cat
```

Comment: So, `Pear <: Fetus` means Pear is some **specific** subtype of `Fetus` and that **specific** subtype is not `Apple`??  But, why can't `Pear` be an `Apple` ? All the compiler knows is that `Pear` is a subtype of `Fetus`. It could or could not be an Apple.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it makes sense now.

Comment: I think Tzach's quote: `...abstract types are specifications that may resolve to zero, one, or many classes.` implies that `Pear` is not a specific type in your example but any of a range of possible subtypes. And thats why `Apple` cant be put into a box of `Pears` because its unclear what the range of the box is. In your second example, you restrict `Fruit` to a supertype of `Apple` and thats why the type coercion happens.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing the meaning of the definition 
`type T <: Fruit`: It's an *abstract type* defintion (unlike `type T = Fruit` which is a *type alias*). Absract types do not *create* a class T that extends `Fruit`, rather it is an *abstract declaration* that must be overridden in some subclass to be used.

From [Learning Scala, chapter 10](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-scala/9781449368814/ch10.html):

> ... abstract types are specifications that may resolve to zero, one, or many classes. They work in a similar way to type aliases, but being specifications they are abstract and cannot be used to create instances

Notice that the declaration `type T <: Fruit` can only reside in a class/trait (not an object, nor top-level definitions), because it's meaningless until that class/trait is extended. Where it is defined, it's still abstract and therefore compiler can't know for sure that `Apple` extends it.

An example for using such a definition:

```
trait Price {
  type T <: Fruit
  def printPrice(x: T): Unit
}

class ApplePrice extends Price {
  override type T = Apple
  override def printPrice(x: Apple): Unit = ???
}
```

Here, `ApplePrice` must override this abstract type with something. Another subclass of `Price` might override this with something different (e.g. `Banana extends Fruit`), which should make it clear that the expression `val t: T = Apple("apple")` placed in `Price` can't compile - for some possible extending class, `T` isn't `Apple`, nor does `Apple` extend `T`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `abstract type` vs `type aliases` thing. But, abstract types seemingly can be used as type ascriptions ( is that similar to saying that an abstract type does connote a class?) Also, what do you think of Dmitriy's reasoning? It seems intuitive.

Comment: Dmitriy's answer is perfectly correct, I just assumed the nature of the abstract definition was the issue in need of clarification. Eventually, both answers together give the complete picture: being abstract, type T _might_ end up being some type which isn't a supertype of `Apple`, so compiler can't let an `Apple` be assigned to it.

Comment: Ahh, the compiler could only coerce `Apple` to type `T` iff `T` was a supertype of `Apple`. And that does not hold because `T` could be a subtype of `Apple` or actually neither i.e. placed horizontally like Dimitry mentioned. Thanks, it all makes sense now!